# PyCharm helpers not appearing in vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm, remote-debugging

I'm trying to configure remote debugging in pycharm on vagrant, but when I run I get the following error:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/local/strongarm_venv/bin/python2.7 -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client '0.0.0.0' --port 49921 --file /vagrant/manage.py runserver 8000
/usr/local/strongarm_venv/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've searched the internet and my entire drive for a directory called ".pycharm_helpers" but all I can find is that pycharm was supposed to have created it at some point on the VM, which it hasn't done. Where can iI find a copy of it to manually insert, or how do I tell pycharm to put it there?

Answer (score 9):

If you go to the Default Settings under Default Project > Project Interpreter, and make sure your Vagrant VM's python is selected as the Project Interpreter.

If it is not shown as the current selection, drop down the list of interpreters and select it.

Most likely, if it is not appearing as the selected interpreter, the vagrant machine does not match the configuration when you first connected the interpreter to the machine, in which case the PyCharm will try to fix it.

If it fails to fix it, remove the interpreter and add it back again.

Comment: Removing and adding it back did it for me. I had changed the base image to work from since setting up the interpreter, so the ssh credentials for accessing the machine was not correct in the settings. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If the other variations here didn't work for you, you might want to delete the `.pycharm_helpers` folder from the VM. Open a SSH session to your Vagrant machine:

```
Tools > Start SSH Session... > Vagrant at \your\path\to\vagrant
```

Run the following:

```
-rf /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/
```

This will delete the PyCharm helpers. Next you'd like to get them reinstalled.

```
File > Settings > Project: primary > Project Interpreter
```

Change the `Project Interpreter` to your default interpreter. Click `Apply`, then back to the vagrant VM, and click `Apply` again.

This should make `.pycharm_helpers` download again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after updating project's vagrant box.
So, the easiest way to fix it is to remove Project Interpreter in the Settings and then to add it again.
After that you'll see that PyCharm updates its helpers for new interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm is supossed to have uploaded these files to the vagrant VM when loading the remote interpreter. Something may be wrong with your connection to the vagrant machine, are you able to connect via ssh from pycharm to the VM?

Comment: yes but the question is, why pycharm does not install it?

Comment: I can't think of a specific reason, how is your interpreter configured ? Are you using a deployment configuration ?

Comment: it seems it was temp problem. restarting mac/vagrant fixed it :(

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me if i started IntelliJ before my Vagrant instance. Or if did `vagrant destroy/up` while IntelliJ was running. Just restarting IntelliJ (or PyCharm) seemed to trigger a login and create the needed `/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/`.